# Client side validation not working if i am using server side model validation also in CAKEPHP 2.5.2

Tags: php, jquery, cakephp-2.0

I am creating a project using cakephp 2.5.2. I made a simple sign in form with fields of "email" and "password". The file name is admin_index.php inside Login folder.

```
<?php
 echo $this->Form->create('Login', array('novalidate'=> true));
 ?>
  <div class="log-input">
  <div class="log-input-left">
     <?php echo $this->Form->input('email',array('class'=>'user required','label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Enter Email')); ?>        
  </div>
 <div class="clearfix"> </div>    
 </div>
 <div class="log-input">
    <div class="log-input-left">
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('password',array('class'=>'lock required','label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Enter Password')); ?>          
    </div>
 <div class="clearfix"> </div>
</div>
<?php
 $options = array(
    'label' => 'Login'   
);
 echo $this->Form->end($options);
 ?>

     </div>
    <div class="new_people">
        <h4>For New People</h4>
             <p>Having hands on experience in creating innovative designs,I do offer design 
                                    solutions which harness.</p>
                            <a href="sign-up.html">Register Now!</a>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
     </div>
    <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $('#LoginAdminIndexForm').validate({ 

        });
   });
  </script>
```

I want to apply both type of validation that is client side and server side also. For client side validation i include jquery.valdation.js file and call script for validate fields in ctp file. And for server side validation, write a rule on model file(Model/Login.php).

```
<?php
 class Login extends AppModel {
       public $useTable = 'admins'; 
       var $validate = array(
          'email' => array(
              'email_must_not_be_blank' => array(
              'rule' => 'notEmpty',
              'message' => 'Email cant be blank.'
          ),
             'email_must_be_valid_syntax' => array(
             'rule' => 'email',
             'message' => 'Email is not valid.'
        ),
        'email_must_be_unique' => array(
            'rule' => 'isUnique',
            'message' => 'Email is already exist.'
        ),
    ),
    'password' => array(
        'length' => array(
            'rule'      => array('between', 5, 40),
            'message'   => 'Your password must be between 8 and 40 characters.',
        ),
    )
);
}
```

Controller file is:

```
class LoginsController extends AppController {
public $uses = array('Login');
public $name='Login';
public function admin_index() {
         if($this->request->is('post')){ 
            $this->Login->set($this->request->data);                
            if ($this->Login->validates()) {

            } else {
                $errors = $this->Login->validationErrors;
            }
        }
        $this->layout = 'login';
        $this->render('admin_index');
}
```

}

The problem is, client side validation is working fine if i am not applying model validation but on using both side validation, jquery validation do not work. Means, firstly jquery validation should call but in this case server side validation working instead of jquery validation. 
Also, I include jquery library and jquery.validation.js file inside layout folder.
Can somebody help me out from this problem.

Comment: i don't see any javascript in your question, where is the front-end validation ??

Comment: front-end validation is put in ctp file at bottom of the page.                        <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $('#LoginAdminIndexForm').validate({ 

        });
   });
  </script>

Comment: and the parameters for that script,where are they?

Comment: i used required class in input type email and password. On adding required class, jquery.validation.js file automatically validate the fields.